# R translate output of t.test() to other languages

Tags: r, customization

Is there a fast way to customize the names of the output so that, for instance, I get "moyenne" instead of "mean", or "T-test pour échantillon unique" instead of "One Sample t-test". To start with, let us focus on the standard functions from r-base, like t.test() or summary().

Of course I could save the .tex files produced by pandoc, before getting the .pdf and make the translations at that level, but this looks pretty tedious.

Many LaTeX packages support some kind of "internationalization" (e.g. the Exercise package) so I wonder if something similar is available for the R packages needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `getAnywhere(t.test.default)`, you will get the code for `t.test`.

You can copy this, and make the required changes. For example change `"mean of x"` to `"moyenne de x"`. Save the copy as a new function `t_french <- ...`.

```
t_french(1:10)

#T-test pour échantillon unique

#données:  1:10
#t = 5.7446, df = 9, p-valeur = 0.0002782
#hypothèse alternative: moyenne réelle ne correspond pas à 0
#95 intervalle de confiance pour cent:
# 3.334149 7.665851
#estimations de l'échantillon:
#moyenne de x
#         5.5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It looks very promising. However, when comparing the amount of manipulations needed from this solution with that of manually changing the .tex file, I feel I'de better do it manually, unless I have to do it several times. 

On the other hand, there is a great idea arising from this : write the usual functions so as to obtain the outputs in other languages... That would be great. I don't know much about this, but perhaps an extra argument for te t.test() function allowing the specify the desired output language could be interesting!